# How to Filter a date column to show the last week day of a month only

Tags: excel, date, filter

I would like to know how to filter a date column in excel 2003 to show the last weekday date of a month only.

I tried making another column with TRUE/ FALSE outputs using the formula =DAY(N8+1)=1, which returns true if the day referenced is the end of the month. However, this formula returns false if the last weekday of the month is NOT the last day of the month, ie 12/29/2006. How can I get it so the expression returns true for the last weekday of the month (after that I can sort the column by whether it is true/false).

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(B3),MONTH(B3)+1,0),2)>5,
    DATE(YEAR(B3),MONTH(B3)+1,0)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(B3),MONTH(B3)+1,0),2)+5,
    DATE(YEAR(B3),MONTH(B3)+1,0))
```

Note how I use `DATE(YEAR(B3),MONTH(B3)+1,0)` to get the date of the last day of the month, test if it's "greater" than Friday, and if so, subtract from it the number of days by which it is greater than Friday.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This was good for putting into serial form. In the end what I ended up doing was making another column of the month number only using Months(). Then, in an adjacent column, I put the formula =IF(L9<=L8,"FALSE","TRUE"), which basically returns a false if the nest row is the same month as the current row. Thus, a "TRUE" only shows up at the end of a month. I then filter by True/false. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

You can add a formula in a column to autofilter on.
[Chip Pearon's site has a formula which shows this](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DateTimeWS.htm#LastWeekday) and he is an invaluable resource

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+1,0)-(MAX(0,WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+1,0),2)-5))
```

Comment: Nice, more concise than mine. +1 to Chip Pearson :-)